# SQLite : Need to combine results from one table with another result

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables :

payments:

```
id  amount  type    code
1   1200    0       111
2   100     1       111
3   200     0       111
4   50      0       112
5   500     2       112
6   300     3       113
```

bills:

```
id  details     code
-----------------------
1   bill-1      111 
2   bill-2      112
3   bill-3      113
4   bill-4      114
```

I wanted to sum the `amounts` in `payments` table and join it with `bills` like below

result:

```
bills.code  type0Sum    type1Sum    type2Sum    type3Sum
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
111         1400        100         0           0
112         50          0           500         0
113         0           0           0           300
114         0           0           0           0
```

Sorry if this is a newbie question

[Edit]
I have used a similar query as below :

```
SELECT *
FROM bills, 
     (SELECT SUM(amount) AS type0Sum, code
             FROM payments
             WHERE type = 0
             GROUP BY code) 
      AS sub1,
      (SELECT SUM(amount) AS type1Sum, code
              FROM payments
              WHERE type = 1
              GROUP BY ref_code) 
      AS sub2
      WHERE bills.code = sub1.code
      AND bills.code = sub2.code
```

But I am getting only the rows those having the *type* like :

```
bills.code  type0Sum    type1Sum    type2Sum    type3Sum
    -------------------------------------------------------
    111         1400        100
```

Comment: You're right, this is a newbie question. Instead of doing it for you let's help you learn. What have you tried already, what are you struggling with?

Comment: @RichBenner : There was a layout issue in my question, hopes my question is clear now.

Comment: In your question you mention the two operators that you need: SUM and JOIN (hint: you'll want a GROUP BY too). Google those operators and have a read, you'll learn much more from this than us doing it for you.

Comment: @RichBenner: Yes I have googled a lot before posting this question. I have tried various combinations and final one which is near to my requirement is added in my question. Hope it will shed more light.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've put my response in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified that final query to do proper joins, not the old joins that you were doing (read up on cartesian joins). Give this one a go for you, see if it works;

```
SELECT b.code
    ,sub1.type0Sum
    ,sub2.type1Sum
FROM bills b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(amount) AS type0Sum
        ,code
    FROM payments
    WHERE type = 0
    GROUP BY code
    ) AS sub1 ON b.code = sub1.code
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(amount) AS type1Sum
        ,code
    FROM payments
    WHERE type = 1
    GROUP BY ref_code
    ) AS sub2 ON b.code = sub2.code
```

There are other ways of doing this that are more efficient but I've kept to your query in order to help you learn.